# How to change background Color of Navigationbar programmatically in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a navigationbar in UWP project on Xamarin.

```
App.xaml.cs
...
public app()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage()){
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
  }
}
```

So If I am in Setting Page, I need to change the color of Navigationbar programmatically.

```
SettingPage.xaml.cs

...
private void clicked_btn(sender, e) {
  ...
  // how can I get the handle of navigationbar and then change the attribute of one???
}
```

Is that possible?

Is there a way I can do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its better not do it, or do it via custom renderers. 
But below is the forms approach :

```
var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
```

Answer (score 12):

From class definition you can set the bar background color. Like this.

```
namespace ProyectName
{
    public class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#484559");
            BarTextColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Or from your App.xml add a ResourceDictionary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="StockIt.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Primary">#484559</Color>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: After scrolling around on trying to do this dynamically from Android settings, this was the way to go for me. Specifically setting the style within the App.xaml ResourceDictionary. Hint: if you're trying to set this by changing between a dark/light theme, you can use an AppThemeBinding like so 
                ```<Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource GrayDark}}" />```