# Dynamically change Android Toolbar/Tabbar theme

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to dynamically change my Toolbar theme within a Android application. I have a custom light and dark theme themes/styles. These are dynamically changed within the application, and for the most part the UI updates. The positive and negative style buttons update properly, but the ActionBar theme does not.
The *styles.xml* file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />

    <!-- Light Themes -->
    <style name="DayTheme" parent="MainTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>"
    </style>

    <style name="DayTheme.ActionBar" parent="MainTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/whiteSmoke</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@color/whiteSmoke</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/whiteSmoke</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Dark Themes -->
    <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#999999</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NightTheme" parent="MainTheme" >
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>"
    </style>

    <style name="NightTheme.ActionBar" parent="MainTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/grayDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/whiteSmoke</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@color/whiteSmoke</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/whiteSmoke</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I am unsure how to reference this in the *Toolbar.xml* file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

Specifically, I am doing this in a Xamarin Forms application, but this problem is definitely suited to Android-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this question, I ended up solving this in a Xamarin Forms-specific solution. I already have a custom reference to *AppThemeBinding* in Xamarin Forms, so I was able to set the theme of the NavigationPage using:

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource GrayDark}}" />
    <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{StaticResource WhiteSmoke}" />
</Style>
```

Thankyou to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45890741/13902576.
I kept the Toolbar.xml layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I know this isn't an Android solution, but if anyone else is using Xamarin Forms hopefully this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` maybe it will help.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work with Xamarin forms, I was hoping I wouldn't have to go down that track and was thinking their was an easy custom Android solution rather than using Material. Thank you though :)